# GTranslate Wordpress show one language if another one is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-translate

I have two language to select in my wordpress page, Indonesia and English.
The condition is:
Default language is **English**, so if I click Indonesian flag the language is change to Indonesia and the English flag is **hide**, vice versa.

Somebody help me?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, please edit your question to make it clear. Thanks!

Comment: I think that is the normal behavior. If you set the Widget look to "Dropdown", it will help you.